# is there an easy to use formula for switching the datatype on a table column from int to bit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I'm looking at a sql server table, and one of the columns seems to have been setup to be of type INT NULL when it's really better off as a BIT NOT NULL.

Is there an easy formula or shortcut for switching the type?

---

My current strategy is:

- add new temp column
- populate with data based on old column contents
- drop old column and constraints
- rename new column to old column name
- add constraints based on new column

this seems complicated but, really, should be automatable - so i'm wondering if anyone's automated it yet.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48872/quickly-change-null-column-to-not-null

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29522/why-does-alter-column-to-not-null-cause-massive-log-file-growth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update MyTable set MyColumn = 0 where MyColumn is null
```

Assuming you want null to be false

```
Alter table MyTable alter column MyColumn bit not null
```

Will do the job, given all non-zero values are to be treated as true.

Course you were going to backup before you did any of this weren't you. :)

Comment: PS if you have an index on this column, you might want to give it a once over as it's unlikely to be useful.